# IOS 14.7.1 and WordPress Drop Down

Tags: ios, wordpress

I am supporting a website that has a drop down menu (1800sweeper.com) and it was brought to my attention that the dropdown menu for the states on the front page does not work on iOS 14.7.1 so I am testing with an emulator and I tried this setting safari to block cookies and the drop down works but when I set to unblock cookies the dropdown does not direct me to the page in question it does nothing. This works perfectly fine in Chrome, so I am curious if this may be device specific as it does not make much sense that it works when I block cookies?

Comment: https://teamcornett.com/news/advertising-tracking-changes maybe related?

Comment: Agreed but is there any workaround for this I have tried adding data-cookieconsent="ignore" to the select box but it does not seem to have any effect